# Oracle SQL query with multiple conditions based on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a dataframe in the following format:

| PID | Date1 | Date2 | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17750A | 03/07/1960 | 06/07/2009 | A1B3 |
| 17758X | 03/07/1960 | 06/07/2009 | A1B3 |
|  | 06/09/1961 | 11/05/2013 | A2B2 |
| 28363D | 20/11/1964 | 05/03/2019 | A1A2 |
| 30050A | 30/06/1961 | 18/07/2017 | A1B3 |
|  | 04/11/1961 | 16/10/2008 | A2B2 |

And an Oracle database with a table as follows:

| ID | DateA | DateB | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17750A | 03/07/1960 | 06/07/2009 | A1B3 |
|  | 03/07/1960 | 06/07/2009 | A1B3 |
| 20964Q | 06/09/1961 | 11/05/2013 | A2B2 |
| 28363D | 20/11/1964 | 04/03/2019 | A1A2 |
|  | 30/06/1961 | 19/07/2017 | A1B3 |
| 10832Q | 04/11/1961 | 17/10/2008 | A2B2 |

I need to query the database to return another df containing any record where the ID matches a PID, or where (Date1, Date2) equals (DateA, DateB) - i.e. both dates in a df row match both dates in a table row.

So far, I've managed to achieve the first, but not the second.

```
pid_list = df['PID'].values
nvars = ','.join(f':{i}' for i in range(len(pid_list)))

sql_query = """
            SELECT
                gd.ID,
                gd.DateA,
                gd.DateB,
                gd.Notes
             FROM table1 as gd
            WHERE gd.ID in (%s)
            """ % nvars
            
df_result = pd_read_sql(sql_query, connection, params=pid_list)
```

How can I expand that to also match on the pair of dates? Is there a way to do this by passing a list of tuples as a param, rather than needing to iterate through pairs of dates? Something like:

```
sql_query = """
            SELECT
                gd.ID,
                gd.DateA,
                gd.DateB,
                gd.Notes
              FROM table1 as gd
             WHERE gd.pid in (%s)
                OR (Date1 = DateA AND Date2 = DateB)
            """ % nvars, dates

df_result = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection, params=(pid_list, (Date1, Date2)))
```

I think the params passed to pd.read_sql() may need to be a dict, but am not sure how to structure this or how to reference the different entries in the SQL query without iterating.

Comment: Your last query seems correct

Comment: The part I'm unsure of is what params to include when using pd.read_sql. Will update to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try selected all data for Query:

```
            SELECT
                gd.ID,
                gd.DateA,
                gd.DateB,
                gd.Notes
             FROM table1 as gd
```

and filter from your DataFrame. Don't execute query with tuple and IN conditions only 1000 values.

or two query and join two result

or create table in oracle and filter query oracle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The database table is very large so extracting all that data and then filtering post hoc is not really practical. I'd normally create a temporary table to hold the initial dataframe and then join to that but unfortunately I don't have the necessary permissions to do that in this particular db. Since the initial dataframe is typically quite small, I've now implemented an interative method, but I'd still really like to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: Usually, I using approach like your with temp table(simple as fast). Of course, may be using unbeautiful decision and tuple conver in string(like with in conditions id)

Answer (score 1):

You will be always limited with the 1000 entry limit (which you may workaround with the split in sublists using `OR`).

For the *date* compare you may use multi-element `IN` list compare as illustrated in the following query

```
select * from tab
where id in ('17750A','20964Q') or
(dateA,dateB) in ( ( date'1960-07-03', date'2009-07-06'),
                   (date'1961-06-30' , date'2017-07-19'))
```